# Sorting my guestbook posts on time/date (php/mySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I need the posts on my guestbook to be sorted by time ascending.
I have been told that I need to add:

```
ORDER by datetime
```

in my code. But I dont know what the correct way to enter this line is.
Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $host = "ZZZ"; // Host name 
    $username = "ZZZ"; // Mysql username 
    $password = "ZZZ"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name = "ZZZ"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name = "ZZZ"; // Table name 

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM ". $tbl_name ." ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "
        <b>    Name: ". $row["name"]."<br>
            Date Added: : ". date('d-m-Y H:i', $row["datetime"]) ."</b><br><br>
            Comment: ". $row["comment"]."<br>
            <br> 
            ";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }



    mysql_close(); //close database
    ?>
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER by datetime`

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli` and `mysql` functions.

Comment: Also your code at http://tr4p.no/addguestbook.php is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php . And you must html-escape your output, otherwise you'll get XSS.

Comment: This code is ***not*** vulnerable to SQL injection itself and there is no user input involved. This *coding technique* is

Comment: I will learn about XSS asap. Sorry didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tbl_name . " ORDER BY datetime ASC";
```

Also you have mysql_close and your other functions are mysqli

Comment: Also as Hanky Panky says datetime is reserved word so surround in backticks, I forgot this.

Comment: It is not a reserved word.

Comment: I dont know who to believe now

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky do you see `(R)` near `datetime` in page you provided?

Comment: Yep you're right. And Ben you have to believe yourself :)